# How do I remove line and marker symbols from plotly hoverinfo?

Tags: r, plotly

I am drawing a simple figure using `plotly` and have customized the hover text using `hoverinfo`, but there is a line and marker symbol included in the hover text that I'd like to remove. Here is an mwe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

demand <- tibble(q = seq(0,100,by=2), wtp = 50 - q/2)

plot_ly(
    demand, x = ~q, y = ~wtp, 
    type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers", 
    text = ~paste(wtp), hoverinfo = "text"
  ) |> 
  layout(hovermode = "y unified")
```

How do I remove the line and marker inside of the hover info box?

[image]

Comment: You're getting the legend-styled tooltip because you've selected `y unified`. If you want the horizontal line, but a traditional tool tip, set `hovermode = "y"` and in `layout.yaxis` look at the `spike`.... parameters, e.g., `layout(hovermode = "y", yaxis = list(showspikes = T, spikemode = 'across', spikesnap = 'cursor')` If that isn't what you're looking for, let me know. [You can see all of the available y-axis parameters here.](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/yaxis/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [Kat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329073/kat) suggestion, I edited `hovermode` and tried to change the format of the `hoverlabel` and `spike` as much as possible to mimic the style of the `hovermode = "y unified"` in the original plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

demand <- tibble(q = seq(0,100,by=2), wtp = 50 - q/2)

plot_ly(
    demand, x = ~q, y = ~wtp, 
    type = "scatter", mode = "lines+markers", 
    text = ~paste(wtp), hoverinfo = "text"
  ) |> 
  layout(hovermode = "y",
         hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "#FFF"),
         yaxis = list(showspikes = T, spikemode = "across", 
                      spikesnap = "cursor", spikecolor = "#000",
                      spikedash = "dot", spikethickness = 1))
```

[image]